# Hyperledger documentation questions

Tags: hyperledger

I am going through the [Hyperledger documentation on architecture](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/arch-deep-dive.html). I am not able to follow some of the symbols and text. For example,

> Both V and N contain a special element \bot,

What does \bot mean?

> for k\in K and v\in V,

What do k\ and \v mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the architecture section on the Hyperledger documentation is highly mathematical. Some of the symbols (or *intended* symbols) may have come from another source and are not properly rendered in the document.

The `\bot` symbol in LaTeX represents the empty type or falsum: ⊥. In the particular case of the state mapping `K -> (V X N)`, the author is just trying to explain that all values and versions are empty when a key is initialized.

The `\in` symbol represents the relation "is a member of": k ∈ K and v ∈ V.

Comment: I am conversant with math symbols. It is definitely better to have them render correctly.

Comment: I agree. For the record, I opened a JIRA issue for this and will fix the documentation soon. Thanks for bringing up the issue.